# Cooking Chicken in Skillet?

Tags: chicken, skillet

So Im paranoid when it comes to raw meat/undercooking stuff. Sometimes however I want to stick with something simple: IE chicken in a skillet w/ a simple glaze (like sesame/etc....)

However like I have no clue "How long" I should cook it to get a rough idea?

Is there like a good way to tell by looking when chicken is cooked through?

I cook most stuff via cast iron skillet if that matters?

Comment: Looking only at the outside, or does "looking" include cutting a piece open to check the interior appearance?

Comment: Will vary by cut, size, temp and how much oil is used.

Comment: @Paparazzi - skillet covered or uncovered.... the variations are endless.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are paranoid about under-cooking meat, then use a digital probe thermometer and cook it to its safe temperature. No amount of timings or looking at the colour will give you the same level of certainty. They are available online for very little and are extremely handy; not only will you not under-cook your meat, but you will also avoid over-cooking it as well.

Answer (score 1):

When I cook chicken on a skillet I flatten the chicken breast between a piece of parchment paper using a rolling pin. This ensures that the breast is flatter and can cook evenly.

I would recommend that you cook it for 6-8 minutes each side.